# How to add an image in next js api route using cloudinary

Tags: next.js13, cloudinary, nextjs-image

i am unable to add cloudinary in next js api route when i add image to my public folder it works fine but after deploying to vercel it says no path found so i am using cloudinary but got no proper idea of how to implement cloudinary in nextjs api route to upload image.